# Message not passing between content ad background script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send message from `background.js` to contentscript file,`script.js`. Below is code

**script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
//    alert('Message from View:\n'
//          + JSON.stringify(msg));
    alert(msg);
    if (msg.method === 'sendHTML')
    {
        //process the return code

        sendResponse({ data: "Your DOM is here"});
    }
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab)
{
//    var url = tab.url.toLowerCase();
//    if(url.indexOf("middlecoin") == -1)
//        alert("You are not on MiddleCoin Page");
//    else
//        chrome.tabs.create({ url: loaderURL + tab.id });
    alert("Clicked Call");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "sendHTML"}, function(response) {
      alert(response.data);
    });

});
```

the alert `response.data)` is not being called. Where am I doing wrong?

Let me tell there is NO html file is being in entire extension

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) instead of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to send a message from background page to content script. To send a message to the current tab, you can use the tab object passed to your listener for `browserAction.onClicked`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {method: "sendHTML"}, function(response) {
    alert(response.data);
  });
});
```